# UISlider constant distance away from bottom when AutoSizing

Tags: iphone, constants, distance, autoresize, autorotate

I want to fix a UISlider a constant distance away from the bottom of the screen. I can do this easily in the interface builder size inspector. I would simply use the red I shaped locks at the edge of autosizing square. In the image below it would lock to the top left.

I want to lock to the bottom and do it programmatically, not with interface builder.

I've been using the following code to resize but i now want it locked to the bottom :
view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)

Please help.

[image: Size Inspector]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have flexible top margin. You can also add `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` to see how it resizes horizontally.

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Comment: SOLVED: Thank you. I did try that earlier but did it on a different object.